# Facing Error in Codeigniter Multiple Database Connection

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter

im trying to connect multiple database in CI. unable to get connect the second database because new connection is located in different server. 
Step 1: Database.php

```
$active_group = 'default';
$active_record = TRUE;

$db['default']['hostname'] = 'localhost'; //www.maestromindsolutions.com
$db['default']['username'] = 'maestrom_XXX';
$db['default']['password'] = 'XXXXXX';
$db['default']['database'] = 'maestrom_XXX';
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['default']['pconnect'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;

$db['newdb']['hostname'] = '49.50.76.69:2083'; //www.bazaarzone.com
$db['newdb']['username'] = 'bazaarzo_XXX';
$db['newdb']['password'] = 'XXXXXXXX';
$db['newdb']['database'] = 'bazaarzo_XXX';
$db['newdb']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';
$db['newdb']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['newdb']['pconnect'] = FALSE;
$db['newdb']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['newdb']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['newdb']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['newdb']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['newdb']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['newdb']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['newdb']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['newdb']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

Step 2 :Then i done the changes in /system/database/DB_driver.php:

```
function simple_query($sql)
{
    if ( ! $this->conn_id)
    {
        $this->initialize();
    }

    $this->db_select(); //<-----------------  Added this line
    return $this->_execute($sql);
}
```

Step 3: finally i mention the new database connection in model page:

```
$data_contact=array(
        'enq_id'=>$enq_id,
        'enq_name'=>$this->input->post('name'),
        'enq_mobile'=>$this->input->post('mobile'),
        'enq_email'=>$this->input->post('email'),
        'is_active'=>'1'
        );

        $query=$this->db->insert('enquiry',$data_contact);

        // load second database
        $this->newdb = $this->load->database(newdb, true);
        $query=$this->newdb->insert('enquiry',$data_contact);
        return $query;
```

Step 4: when i execute the contact form i got below error  :

```
A Database Error Occurred
Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings.

Filename: core/Loader.php

Line Number: 224
```

Please help me to fix this issue, why multiple database not working with different server ?
Thank you Stackflow..

Comment: Any one please help me to fix this issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not tested this. I have given a way how it should work, without making any changes in core files. Separate Config and objects for separate db connections.

```
$config['hostname'] = "localhost";
$config['username'] = "myusername";
$config['password'] = "mypassword";
$config['database'] = "mydatabase";
$config['dbdriver'] = "mysql";
$config['dbprefix'] = "";
$config['pconnect'] = FALSE;
$config['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$config['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$config['cachedir'] = "";
$config['char_set'] = "utf8";
$config['dbcollat'] = "utf8_general_ci";

$db1 = $this->load->database($config, TRUE);

$config['hostname'] = "localhost";
$config['username'] = "myusername";
$config['password'] = "mypassword";
$config['database'] = "mydatabase";
$config['dbdriver'] = "mysql";
$config['dbprefix'] = "";
$config['pconnect'] = FALSE;
$config['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$config['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$config['cachedir'] = "";
$config['char_set'] = "utf8";
$config['dbcollat'] = "utf8_general_ci";

$db2 = $this->load->database($config, TRUE);
```

Then you can run queries like

```
$db1->query();
$db2->result();
```

Comment: i tried above solution but not working for me. thank you for your response

Answer (score 0):

```
$active_group = 'default';
$active_record = TRUE;
```

This is the part which sets the group name. Notice on the 'default' db the first parameter of the array is `['default']`. You just need to add:

```
$active_group = 'newdb';
$active_record = TRUE;
```

To the top of your second connection.

Alternatively you could have a manual connection setup in your model. I'd only advise that if you don't intend to use the DB on more than one page.

https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/configuration.html

Answer (score 0):

```
$config['db_debug'] = TRUE;
```

**try to change above code to**

```
$config['db_debug'] = FALSE;
```